# Remove Matched Pattern from Beginning of First Line in Text File

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to remove a matched pattern (`-import_file`) from the beginning of the first line in a text file. Using `sed` vs. `awk` seems like the way to go.

**Attempt**

```
sed -i 's/^-import_file//g' /home/weather/f00.txt
```

**f00.txt**

```
-import_file file1 -rpn sto_1
-import_file file2 -rpn sto_2
-import_file file3 -rpn sto_3
-import_file file4 -rpn sto_4
-import_file file5 -rpn sto_5
-import_file file6
```

This does not appear to actually be doing anything to the first matched pattern at the start of Line 1.

Comment: Are you on Mac? Try `sed -i '' 's/^-import_file//g' file` then

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I am on an Ubuntu OS

Comment: Ok, if you remove `^`, does it work?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: No idea, I also have Ubuntu and it works. Please share the file with us.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I provided the file in it's entirety in the original post

Comment: Cool, so it means the question has been closed correctly: your code works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this near-equivalent POSIX AWK solution (removes leading space from edited line):

```
awk 'NR==1 {$1=""; print substr($0,2); next} 1' ~weather/f00.txt > temp && mv temp ~weather/f00.txt
```

I could not replicate your issue on my machine.

```
$ sed --version |head -1
sed (GNU sed) 4.4

$ sed '1s/^-import_file//g' ~weather/f00.txt
 file1 -rpn sto_1
-import_file file2 -rpn sto_2
-import_file file3 -rpn sto_3
-import_file file4 -rpn sto_4
-import_file file5 -rpn sto_5
-import_file file6
```

Comment: This appears to remove first and subsequent lines. The question only asks for the first line.

Comment: @jww I was unsure whether to replicate OP's code or their intent. Both solutions now reflect intent.

Comment: Thanks for the `awk` solution @vintnes. `sed` worked better for me in this instance.

Comment: I didn't realize that I needed to specify using only Line 1 in `sed`